# Is EU covid vaccination certificate good to enter Colombia?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, covid-19, colombia

In December 2021 Colombia introduced a new regulation requiring all international travellers to be vaccinated against COVID in order to enter the country.

Is a person vaccinated in EU and having the standards EU vaccination certificate with QR code going to be accepted in order to enter Colombia?

Does it have to be printed, a PDF or is the COVID Pass app going to work too?

Answer (score 1):

El Salvador, Panama and Uruguay use the EU Digital COVID Certificate system, so the system should be familiar to them.

- [Recognition by the EU of COVID certificates issued by third (non-EU) countries](https://ec.europa.eu/info/live-work-travel-eu/coronavirus-response/safe-covid-19-vaccines-europeans/eu-digital-covid-certificate_en#recognition-by-the-eu-of-covid-certificates-issued-by-third-non-eu-countries)

A printed (or PDF) version should filfill the main conditions:

> [Health Alert: New Vaccination/Testing Requirements to Enter Colombia by Sea - U.S. Embassy in Colombia](https://co.usembassy.gov/health-alert-new-vaccination-testing-requirements-to-enter-colombia-by-sea/)
> The proof of vaccination must be presented either in paper format or digitally. **The certification must include the individual’s full name, date of vaccination, name of the vaccine administered, and the number of doses administered**.